# Determining if $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to determine whether $W = {\{(x, y, z) | x = 3y, z = -y}\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.

If someone can help me understand how to go about doing this that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

$W$ is a subspace since it's the kernel of $\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&0\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check that the zero vector of $\mathbb R^3$ is in the set $W$. If not, it's not a subspace, if so,
2) Check that if $u,v\in W$, then $u+v\in W$. If not, then it's not a subspace, if so, 
3) Check that if $u\in W$ and $t\in \mathbb R$, then $t\cdot u\in W$. If not, it's not a subspace, if so, then it is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the *one-step subspace test*.

**Proposition.** Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\varnothing\neq W\subset V$. Then $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $\lambda_1\cdot w_1+\lambda_2\cdot w_2\in W$ whenever $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb R$ and $w_1,w_2\in W$.

Can you apply this Proposition to your situation? I'll post more hints if you need them.

Comment: This only works for nonempty $W$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to performing a subspace test, we can just note that it's a span:  we see that
\begin{align*}
W &= \{(3y,y,-y):y \in \mathbb{R}\} \\
  &=\mathrm{span}\{(3,1,-1)\}
\end{align*}
and [spans are subspaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span).

Comment: This is my favorite way of doing this.